# Help with "advanced" shell scripting | how to create an image preview of a pdf

Tags: 12.10, command-line, bash, apache2, pdf

First of all, sorry for my english: i'm not british/american.

Here is my problem.
I've got a folder named pdf with lots of files pdf inside it.
I've got another folder named thumbnail, which is empty.
I want to create jpg images preview of each pdf to use them in my HTML webpages as previews of the pdf.

To do this I'm using a software called IMAGEMAGICK.
I tried to put the code inside my PHP files to get the purpose, but it doesn't work. As you understood, I have created a small search engine with apache, mysql to search for pdf locally (offline). Now I want to add a "preview" of the first page of pdfs.
Instead, it works by bash command line and the code is:

```
convert pdf/name_of_the_file_pdf.pdf[0] name_of_the_imagefile.jpg
```

(The zero stands for that the image is taken from the FIRST page of pdf)
How can i make a script that takes each name of pdf files and put it into that code????
To list all the file, I did

```
ls >pdf
```

but with the little knowledge I have I can't go further....
Some pdf's names contain spaces....Is that a problem?

PDF files are so many that i can't do the task typing every name,it wouldn't be a nice and clever work!!!! 
Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any solution that uses the `ls` command will eventually fail, but don't fret; bash can handle any and all filenames safely without involving an external command (like `ls`) to "list" them.

To make a filename.jpg from every filename.pdf in the current directory, you can do:

```
for file in ./*.pdf; do
    convert "$file[0]" "${file%.pdf}.jpg"
done
```

You can also do that in one line

```
for file in ./*.pdf; do convert "$file[0]" "${file%.pdf}.jpg"; done
```

The double quotes (`"`) are very important to avoid wordsplitting and pathname expansion from the result of the parameter expansions.

`$file` and `${file%.pdf}` are called parameter expansions. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100 for more on parameter expansions and string manipulation in bash in general.

EDIT:
And reading the question again, I see you wanted the jpegs in the parent directory of the pdfs, so I'll include the necessary modifications for that as well:

```
for file in pdf/*.pdf; do
    basename=${file##*/}
    convert "$file[0]" "./${basename%.pdf}.jpg"
done
```